# To add soffits vents or not

Tags: roof, ventilation, soffit, gable

I am in the process of getting a new roof and the roofer suggested that I should add soffit vents.  This is a 1970s era home that has large gables on the sides.  Please note on the higher level of the house,the gables are covered due to adding spray foam on the roof. The lower level of the house has regular fiberglass insulation and a powered attic fan at the top with no ridge vent.  Would you suggest soffits to be added?[image: left side of house]

[image: right side of house]

Comment: I'm confused about the insulation situation. Are you saying the upper roof is "hot", with insulation against the sheathing?

Comment: And did you also omit "vents" where you said "gables"?

Comment: The upper isn't hot at all.  I did omit vents when referring to the gables.

Comment: I assume the roofer is also recommending installing ridge vents?

Comment: Yes they did suggest that.

Comment: @GMD I don't think roofers will do a ridge vent without eave (soffit) vents.

Answer (score 1):

You already have soffits. Is he suggesting ventilated soffits? In that case, you don't need them where ventilation is blocked, and you should add them where you have the ventilated attic. It's easy for a roofer to add a ridge vent, and it will help prevent ice dams.

Comment: No.  I currently do not have any soffit vents.  Just gable vents.

Comment: Your original question said soffit instead of vents. Now that you fixed it, my answer still stands. Put vents where air can follow into the attic. Since you are doing a roof, might as well ask for a ridge vent, since it's a small step once the roofers remove the old roof.

Comment: Check with your spouse or other vote having members of the household. For some odd reason, my wife doesn't like the look of ridge vents - she'd rather have the big box vents.